# anychart doen't change with data

Tags: android, firebase, spinner, anychart

I'm trying to use anychart with a data stored in firebase, i added a spinner to filter the data i used `log.e` to know if my data changes and i conclude that the data changes pretty good but the problem is my pie chart doen't update with the new data this is my code

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);``

        anyChartView= (AnyChartView)findViewById(R.id.chart11);

        pie= AnyChart.pie();
        dataEntries=new ArrayList<>();
        dataEntries.clear();

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                ref3.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String s2;
                        dataEntries.clear();

                        for (int i=0;i<list2.size();i++){
                            s2=dataSnapshot.child(list2.get(i)).child("category").getValue(String.class);
                            s=spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: s &&& s2"+s+"    "+s2 );

                            if (s.equals(s2)){

                                dataEntries.add(new ValueDataEntry(list2.get(i),Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child(list2.get(i)).child("count").getValue(String.class))));
                                Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: data"+list2.get(i)+"  "+ dataSnapshot.child(list2.get(i)).child("count").getValue(String.class));
                            }else continue;}

                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: size"+dataEntries.size() );

                        anyChartView= (AnyChartView)findViewById(R.id.chart11);

                        pie= AnyChart.pie();
                        pie.data(dataEntries);
                        anyChartView.setChart(pie);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the pie chart you need simply apply new data to the existing pie chart and make it active. There's no need to recreate the chart or something else. For details, check [the explanation with the snippet on our GitHub page](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/108).